# Python 2.7 extract day from Dataframe timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe "signals" like this:

```
                     Date Object        Value  \
0     01/03/2017 00:00:13   Obj1     3.421875   
1     01/03/2017 00:01:13   Obj1     3.578934   
2     01/03/2017 00:02:13   Obj1     3.437500   
3     01/03/2017 00:03:13   Obj1     3.234674  
4     02/03/2017 00:02:13   Obj1     3.056745   
5     02/03/2017 00:03:13   Obj1     4.456456 
6     02/03/2017 00:02:13   Obj1     3.764563   
7     03/03/2017 00:03:13   Obj1     3.345645 
8     03/03/2017 00:02:13   Obj1     3.874566   
9     04/03/2017 00:03:13   Obj1     4.245435 
.....
```

and I would calculate the daily mean values.
How should be written? I guess to be used such as "groupby", something like:

```
mean_values = signals.groupby('Date',sort=True).mean()
```

but I need to "extract" the day info. Otherwise with 'Date' it doesn't group by day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first convert the `Date` column to date time type, and then use `dt.date` to access the date info:

```
import pandas as pd
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)    
df.groupby(df.Date.dt.date).Value.mean()

#Date
#2017-01-03    3.418246
#2017-02-03    3.759255
#2017-03-03    3.610105
#2017-04-03    4.245435
#Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great! That's what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I re-open the thread, just to know: how can I simply plot this dataframe?